# How to run a code repetitively after two seconds in background in android?

Tags: android, service, timer, alarmmanager, applocker

I want to run the given below piece of code repetitively after two seconds, I searched for the solutions many times and find this one.

> The code given below is working only for sometime because Timer is destroyed by system after sometime. I also tried Alarm Manager which starts the service after 2 seconds but consumes too much memory even if the service doesn't contain any code.
>
> Please( its been 3 continous days googling for the solution), suggest some other way to run that bunch of code repetitively in background every 2 second without being destroyed by the system.

```
   Timer timer  =  new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess =runningAppProcessInfo.get(0) ;


                currentAppName = appProcess.processName.toString();


                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(currentAppName))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {  Toast.makeText(MyService.this.getApplicationContext(),appProcess.processName.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            temp=""+currentAppName;

                         }

                    }
                });
            for(int i=0;i<LockedApps.LockedAppsList.size();i++) {

                if (appProcess.processName.toString().contains(LockedApps.preflist.get(i))) {
                    if (flag == 0) {

                        Intent x = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockActivity.class);
                        x.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(x);

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You used Timer and AlarmManager seperately. Why don't you try combination of Timer and AlarmManager , I mean to say repet alarm every 30 seconds or 60 seconds to triger the service which in turn will start the timer.